# Figure outside margins

Tags: spacing, floats, horizontal-alignment, margins, text

I have an image that is larger than my `\textwidth`. What command can I use?
I'm using the class article.

The command I'm using is

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \makebox[\linewidth][]{
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\linewidth]{Figures/Results/1955diffmap.pdf}
    }
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{1955diffmap}
\end{figure}
```

but the problem is that yes it lets the images be outside the margins, but the images is "alone" in the page and the text jumps to the page as in the picture below... I would like the text in the same page and not waste all that space.

I'm wondering if [c] means centered in the page (horizontal and vertical) meanwhile I want just a horizontal centering... in that case how can I change it?

Thanks :)
[image]

Comment: Hi, Welcome! The vertical positioning is because the image is very tall and LaTeX thinks it looks better on a page on its own. Try adding `[hbt!]` after `\begin{figure}`... (but I think LaTeX is right...) see also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat

Comment: Does the image still jump to the next page when you insert it rotated by adding angle=90 to the options of \includegraphics? A rotated image could look much better (proportionate) than the result you get now.